How do I debug why a microSD card never initializes?
I know this is a pretty poorly-formed question, and I'm very open to suggested edits.
I have two revisions of a dense PCB design that includes a STM32H563 microcontroller with its built-in microSD peripheral connected to an SD card slot.  There are ESD diodes on all signal lines, but no other components between slot and MCU.  The circuitry between the slot and controller has not changed between revisions.  The firmware is identical.  I'm using the same microSD card in all tests.
On the older revision, the MCU is able to communicate with the microSD card without any problems across all instances of that revision (four boards).
On the newer revision, the MCU is unable to fully initialize the microSD card.  It can communicate, but invariably gets stuck during the "power on" phase of initialization, waiting for the MSB of OCR to be set (power up status "ready", response to ACMD41; see this page for more info about OCR).  This is the case on all instances of that revision (two boards).
I've added some extra capacitance to the microSD power supply pin, and measured the supply pin with an oscilloscope.  Upon insertion, the supply pin sags by about 200 mV over about 2 microseconds.  That hardly seems significant and doesn't strike me as being the cause of the problem.
OCR from the microSD card indicates it supports the entire common voltage window from 2.7 to 3.6 volts (all nine bits set).  So I really don't believe it's a supply issue.
What else can I probe?  Why would the same card work fine on one set of boards, and yet never set OCR:31 on another?
Note: The SD slot power pin is tied directly to the +3.3 V rail and has 10 uF of nearby extra capacitance.
People like to see code, so here's the code where the problem appears (generated STM library code):
  /* SD CARD */
  /* Send ACMD41 SD_APP_OP_COND with Argument 0x80100000 */
  while ((count < SDMMC_MAX_VOLT_TRIAL) && (validvoltage == 0U))
  {
    /* SEND CMD55 APP_CMD with RCA as 0 */
    errorstate = SDMMC_CmdAppCommand(hsd->Instance, 0);
    if (errorstate != HAL_SD_ERROR_NONE)
    {
      return errorstate;
    }

    /* Send CMD41 */
    errorstate = SDMMC_CmdAppOperCommand(hsd->Instance, SDMMC_VOLTAGE_WINDOW_SD | SDMMC_HIGH_CAPACITY |
                                         SD_SWITCH_1_8V_CAPACITY);
    if (errorstate != HAL_SD_ERROR_NONE)
    {
      return HAL_SD_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE;
    }

    /* Get command response */
    response = SDMMC_GetResponse(hsd->Instance, SDMMC_RESP1);

    /* Get operating voltage*/
    validvoltage = (((response >> 31U) == 1U) ? 1U : 0U);

    count++;
  }

  if (count >= SDMMC_MAX_VOLT_TRIAL)
  {
    return HAL_SD_ERROR_INVALID_VOLTRANGE;
  }

Bit 31 of validvoltage is never set, so count reaches SDMMC_MAX_VOLT_TRIAL and the method exits with the HAL_SD_ERROR_INVALID_VOLTRANGE error code.

Brian A. Henning - Hi, (a) You said that the circuitry & code is the same between working & non-working revisions. But did the layout of SD-related signals or power change between the revisions? (b) Can you supply photos of the relevant part of the two PCBs, in case folks here spot anything concerning? (c) Expanding on point (a), what sort of things did change between the relevant revisions? (d) I think you've described changes you've tried (e.g. adding extra capacitance to the power pin), but have you tried comparing scope traces of signals & power between working & non-working boards?

@SamGibson I really can't share that design info, but what I can say is very, very little changed.  One more trace was added between the MCU and another module, and one LED was added (SD activity, as it happens, but the code doesn't even drive it yet).

So far I've only probed the power supply pin on a working model, and its inrush dip is (as one would expect, absent the extra capacitor added) worse, showing a 2-us, 340-mV dip followed by a long +260-mV overshoot on the recovery.  I can probe other signals another day, but I'm having trouble understanding why those other signals would be playing a role, given that the overall communication seems to be functional.

Brian A. Henning - Thanks for the reply. "I really can't share that design info". OK, so I'll stop here. My experience with questions about such (e.g. encumbered) designs, is that we often need more info than can be provided, meaning further investigation becomes a waste of time & effort (not always, and I hope it doesn't apply here, but that happens often enough). || "very, very little changed" Understood, but looking at what I think you're describing, that "very, very little" change has been enough to break it, so understanding the exact details is important - but you can't tell us :(

Toggling SD card power is a part of SD initialization process. You might need to reduce power capacitor, not to increase it.

@SamGibson I understand.  The logic is certainly sound... something broke it and nothing else changed, so...  Thanks for engaging.  If I can get clearance to share design info, I'll add it.

It turns out that SD in MMC mode (as compared to SPI mode, which is a free section of the SD spec and well documented around the internet) wants pull-ups on all of the data lines.
The STM32H5xx family allows control over internal pull resistors regardless of assigned pin function.  The default generated code sets them to no pull; adding code to set them to pull-up resolves my problem.
The best practice here would be to revise the design to include external pull-ups, but engaging the MCU's internal pull-ups appears to be good enough.  No extra capacitance on the supply line was necessary.
As to why the first variation worked without them?  I can only suppose that the signals had some level of noise that put them right at the edge of operability, such that manufacturing tolerances between boards changed it just enough to break it.  The clock line does induce a bit of high-frequency trash on the data lines due to the layout.
